# Including projects in other projects in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Say I am working on a couple of PHP projects named Framework and Application, where the latter is using the former. When I dive in the Application's classes, I see some of them extending Framework's classes, for example:

```
class Application_Controller extends Framework_Controller
```

When I hover mouse over `Framework_Controller` and click Ctrl, I want the name to become clickable link upon clicking on which the source code of the `Framework_Controller` class from the Framework project will be opened.

Currently I have achieved almost the same thing by adding the Framework codebase path to the "Include path" list (having the Application project opened, go to File/Settings/PHP). The Framework codebase tree appears under "External Libraries" in the Project window. So when I click on `Framework_Controller` as described above the `Framework_Controller` class file gets opened indeed. However, PHPStorm does not take into consideration that the file actually belongs to another project named Framework — it just opens the file. This has the following disadvantages:

1. On the top navigation bar, the full path to the file is shown (i.e.
   starting from "/") rather than starting from the Framework project
   root directory.
2. If I want to edit the file (and possibly more related files in the Framework codebase), I would have to manually switch to the Framework project window and find the same file in there.

So I am wondering if there is any way I could tell PHPStorm that the Application project uses/includes the Framework project, so that when I click on `Framework_Controller` as described above, the `Framework_Controller` class file gets opened *in the Framework project window* rather than just a file external to the Application project.

Comment: **It's not possible**. Instead of "include path" you can add it as a **Content Root** (`Settings | Directories`) -- but it sill still be opened in the same project (with some advantages over "include path" approach). Related: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15187

Comment: Thanks LazyOne. So basically until the feature is implemented, the workaround is to keep both Framework and Application codebases symlinked under a folder called say Project, and treat it as one project in PHPStorm.

Comment: Why symlinked? From IDE point of view these "include paths" or Content Roots can be located anywhere. ATM it's unclear yet how it will be working when that ticket will be implemented. But for your actual web site to work you may indeed need to use symlinks.